# Laravel's default login: Unable to locate [auth-session-status]

Tags: laravel

I am getting the error

> Unable to locate a class or view for component [auth-session-status].

and it points to this line return `$next($request)`;

which is found in this class

```php
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string ...$guards): Response
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;
        $redirecturl ='auth/home';

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect($redirecturl);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
        
    }
```

i was trying to login and expected to login

Comment: Are you sure not this line cause the issue ? `$redirecturl ='auth/home';`

Comment: Check the full stack trace, it should show some other file and line. This file is probably not the cause of the error

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you have something like:

```
<x-auth-session-status />
```

Or:

```
<x-auth-session-status></x-auth-session-status>
```

**But** there was no such view-file at:

```
views/components/auth-session-status.blade.php
```

**Nor** was there any component-class registered (in your `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method), like:

```
use App\Components\MyComponent;

// ...

Blade::component('auth-session-status', MyComponent::class);
```

### Solution(s)

If unlike OP, it's your own or a co-worker's custom component, then:

- Ensure component's related view-file is created at said path.
- Or, ensure component's related component-class is created and as said registerd.

If like OP, it is not a custom-component, and comes from a library, then read their (said library's) install-documentation, there they will either ask you to execute some command(s) to create said view-file(s), or ask you to manually register their component (like above `MyComponent`), in OP's case they [document](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation) following commands:

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
php artisan breeze:install

# And so on:
php artisan migrate
npm install
npm run dev
```

Finally, ensure `auth-session-status` is even correct to begin with, for example, if `auth` is a folder and you have a file like `views/components/auth/session-status.blade.php`, then you should use "." instead of "-", like:

```
<x-auth.session-status></x-auth.session-status>
```